# $\lim_{ n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$ via L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

I just need to find this limit and I don't know how to use L'Hopital's rule in this case:

$$\lim_{ n\to \infty}   \frac{n!}{n^n}.$$

I apologize for the lack of formatting, I've never used the site before.

Comment: look up Stirling's formula, it is divergent, the limit is $\infty$. I don't think one can calculate such limit using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: You couldn't use L'Hopital because we're dealing with sequences, not real valued functions. Stirling's formula doesn't apply either.

Comment: why not? is it because it is only asymptotic?

Comment: I don't see why Stirling's formula wouldn't work, but it is overkill.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Actually the limit is 0.

Answer (score 9):

**hint**: $\dfrac{n!}{n^n} < \dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: That would seem to make things clear, but what process can I show as my work?  I'm afraid I don't understand the forces at work here.

Comment: You can use the squeeze theorem here: $0 < \dfrac{n!}{n^n} < \dfrac{1}{n} \to$ limit $ = 0$.

Comment: Oh wow - okay, that does make a lot more sense now.  Though is there something I need to do to confirm that $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ < $\frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: $\dfrac{n!}{n^n} = \dfrac{1\cdot 2\cdots n}{n\cdot n\cdots n} < \dfrac{1}{n}\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots 1 = \dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ and set  $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$. By ratio test  $\lim\limits_{n->\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{e}<1$. Hence this series is convergent. It follows that $\lim\limits_{n->\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$.

Comment: What do you think about the value of that infinite series?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that $n!$'s order of magnitude is lower than $n^n$'s, so if you are watching $\frac{n!}{n^n}$, the limes must be $0$.

The same way you can prove for example, that $\frac {logn}{n}$ has a limit of $0$ too.

Here are the order of magnitude, in order:

$log n << \sqrt n << n << n^x << x^n << n! << n^n$

All of these are going towars $\infty$, but you can see that left to the right they are faster and faster.

If you divide a smaller one with a bigger one, the limit is $0$, and if you divide a bigger one with a smaller one, the limit is $\infty$

Hope this helps a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx$$ For integer values of $n$ we have $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$

Also for large $n$ values, we can use [The Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_formula)
$$\Gamma(n+1)\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ Therefore
$$\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{n^n}\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac{1}{e}\right)^n$$ Using [L'Hospital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) we can show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt n}{e^n}=0$$ Hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n!}{n^n}=0.$$